# SpringBoot get environment variables for @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, configuration, datasource

I'm struggling with the following problem:

In my springboot project I want to initialize a datasource by myself. Inside that method I want to work with some environment variables which I read from a YML file.

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean
    public JdbcDataSource createMainDataSource() {
        // init datasource and read some environment variables
    }
}
```

Application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/XXX
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Then I defined another class with @Configuration where I obtain the environment variables.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public class PropertiesConfig {

    private String url;

    private String driverClassName;
}
```

But now I have the problem that the class DataSourceConfig is being initialized before PropertiesConfig leading to the problem that I  can't use the environment variables.

Can somebody of you help me with that?

Comment: Why? Also those properties are already bound to an object so why bind it to another object again?

Comment: to which object are they bound? how can I access them then?

Comment: `DataSourceProperties`... Just auatowire it. But why do you need it? There are easier ways of constructing your own datasource (if you really must). But still why would you need to construct your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create your DataSource you need your `PropertiesConfig`, so just inject it into your bean:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private PropertiesConfig propertiesConfig;

    @Bean
    public JdbcDataSource createMainDataSource() {
        // init datasource and read some environment variables
    }
}
```